# How to Checked a CHECKBOX according to a value returned from server

Tags: html, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
     <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'">            
        <div class="col left">
          <button ng-click="viewOrderDetails(x.detail)">订单详情</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col left">
          <button ng-click="viewOrderDetails(x.detail)">打印订单</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col left">
          <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="subcheck" id="processed">上菜/未上菜<P>
        </div>

        <script>
        if ({{x.processed}}=='1'){
        $('#processed').prop('checked', true);
        }else{
        $('#processed').prop('checked', false)
        }
        </script>
    </div>
```

I want to Checked a CHECKBOX (id="processed") according to a value returned from server x.processed. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Stop everything and read this first: ["Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/968155)

Comment: ok, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
    <script>
    if ({{x.processed}}=='1'){
    $('#processed').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
    $('#processed').prop('checked', false)
    }
    </script>
```

With angular, leave the DOM manipulation to angular whenever possible and work off your model.

And use the ng-model

```
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="subcheck" ng-true-value="1" ng-model="x.processed">
```

Comment: @IsaacLi, does `x.processed` equal `1` (number) or `"1"` (string)? This answer works for `1`, but if you need `"1"` then change this answer slightly to have `ng-true-value="'1'"` (notice the `''` quotes). See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JF0tvcg2ACyfcw6pDsZF?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-checked="{{x.processed}}"` to the input with ID of 'processed'

Edit: and remove that jquery code.

Edit2: you probably want to add an `ng-model="x.processed"` to your checkbox element so that Angular will be aware if a user changes it

Comment: This may add the attribute `checked` but it wouldn't change the model associated with it, so to me, this is a wrong approach. @IsaacLi

Comment: The question was asking how to check a checkbox based on a value, it had nothing to do assigning its value to $scope.

Comment: Fair enough, and the OP has accepted this as a solution, which is his prerogative. But, this approach is leading the OP (and others that follow) down a misguided path. How would you then get back which `order` is still checked? Surely, with some jQuery in the controller?

Comment: I am guessing that x.processed is supposed to be a readonly type thing, but I see your point and updated my answer for the future readers.